# How To Convert Date Format that's being used to identify Activesheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that's being used to set up appointments and paste them into the month specific sheet.
What I need is for the full date (dd.mm.yy) to be pasted and not just the "MMM" date.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()


If IsDate(DT.Text) Then

        DT.Text = Format(CDate(Me.DT.Text), "mmm") 'Format as abrivated month

        'Define and Assign worksheet and newRow variables
        Dim ws As Worksheet, newRow As Long
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.DT.Text)
        newRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim dtnew As Long

dtnew = DT.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"

    ws.Range("A" & newRow).Value = dtnew 'Adds the TextBox3 into Col A & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("B" & newRow).Value = GroupName.Text
    ws.Range("D" & newRow).Value = Coordinator.Text
    ws.Range("E" & newRow).Value = Email.Text
    ws.Range("F" & newRow).Value = PhoneNumber.Text
    ws.Range("H" & newRow).Value = NumberPPL.Text
```

How can I get the date from DT.Text to paste as "dd.mm.yy" while still sorting the data into the correct worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format` returns a `Variant/String`. There isn't a date any longer after `DT.Text = Format(CDate(Me.DT.Text), "mmm")`

If that step is absolutely necessary (not sure why it is), then "save the date" :)

```
If If IsDate(DT.Text) Then
    Dim theDate as Date
    theDate = CDate(DT.Text)
```

Then use the date as necessary, `Format`ting it along the way.

```
Dim theMonth as String
theMonth = Format(theDate, "Mmm")

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(theMonth)
...
ws.Range("A" & newRow).Value = theDate
ws.Range("A" & newRow).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yy"
```